# Aggregate SQL query on encrypted column

Tags: sql-server, encryption

We are using SQL Server and have a few columns that are encrypted within a table, and all columns are encrypted as RANDOMIZED. While using a connection with the option *Column Encryption Setting = Enabled*, we are able to see the unencrypted data.

```
select PetAge, PetBreed, EncryptedColumn
from PetData
```

| PetAge | PetBreed | EncryptedColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sausage roll | orange |
| 8 | albatross | yellow |
| 72 | left shoe | red |

We are trying to group by EncryptedColumn and we get an error

```
select PetAge, PetBreed, EncryptedColumn, count(PetBreed)
from PetData
group by EncryptedColumn
```

> Msg 33299, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables 'EncryptedColumn'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDatabase') and the expression near line '3' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC') (or weaker).

Is there a way group by an encrypted column that uses RANDOMIZED encryption?

Comment: Yes, but it's slow. The problem is the "randomized" encryption means a separate random key is stored per row, so the encrypted data actually saved in each row is different _even if the underlying value is the same_. That's bad for GROUP BY, so trying to do such a GROUP BY operation requires first decrypting the data for ALL rows. However, at the point where a GROUP BY operation normally takes place the data is still all encrypted. IIRC there are things you can do with nested SELECTS or CTEs to force the GROUP BY to take place later... but then you've also lost indexes and statistics support.

Comment: That's what I was afraid would be the answer. I'll go that route. If you add your comment as an answer I will mark it.

Comment: The "IIRC" in the middle of my comment is pulling a lot of weight yet. It's something I remember in passing from a long while back, and could be off. I wouldn't take my words too authoritatively yet.

Comment: Using randomized prevents the ability for grouping and joining encrypted columns. The documentation is pretty clear on this point. Check out under point #2 in this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#configure-always-encrypted